# Access CosmosDB emulator from Xamarin app running on Android emulator

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to access CosmosDB emulator from a Xamarin Forms application running from Android emulator. Both emulators run on the same machine. CosmosDB emulator doesn't run in Docker. My code looks like this:

```
var endPoint = "https://localhost:8081/";
var authKey = "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==";
var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endPoint), authKey);
await client.ReadDatabaseAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("mydb"));
```

When I call the ReadDatabaseAsync method I get a SocketException with the message: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)

I have started the CosmosDB emulator with the /AllowNetworkAccess argument and I have set the key same as the key I use on my C# code (which is the default master key for the emulator)

On the Android emulator, I have changed the hosts file and localhost to point to 10.0.2.2. I've verified in Chrome in Android emulator that 10.0.2.2:8081 points to the CosmosDb emulator as I get an authorized access response back.

Anyone had similar issues?

Comment: Why your url looks like "https://localhost:8081/" ? You need to specify the host ip.

Comment: localhost:8081 points to the host ip

Comment: but if you're using it from a mobile app, localhost never will works!

Comment: That's why I edited the hosts file in the emulator. Check the last paragraph in my post.

Comment: because it is https do you have celf-signed cert? That can cause the problem, especially if you use "localhost" but with IP it might too. Check inner exception if it is because of SSL

Comment: Indeed this is what I found out in the end. I changed the httpclient in the Xamarin Android project settings to the Android implementation. Then I got a more detailed exception message. I had a look on the CosmosDB emulator certificate, it was self signed. So in the end I handled the server certificate validation callback and suppressed the error. Should be fine for local use of my app with the emulator.